# Function for Getting Direct Messages from the eBay API

Tags: .net, vb.net, ebay-api

I am making an application to handle the database storage of eBay messages sent to me as the seller. 
I need a way to get the information of direct messages via the .NET eBay API (date, subject, body, sender, etc.)
I am currently using the function 
`.GetMemberMessages(string ItemID, MessageTypeCodeType MailMessageType, MessageStatusTypeCodeType MessageStatus)`, the problem with this function is it only returns messages that originated from items you have listed for sale. Is there a function for getting messages that are not associated with a listed item? Any help would be much appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: could you get message from ebay using getmymessages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your project the [GetMyMessages](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GetMyMessages.html) operation may be what you are looking for.